# Bluez: how to enble hci encryption

Tags: c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

Hi I'm writing about the `hcitool enc <bdaddr>` behavior.
As described in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451162/difference-with-hcitool-lecc-and-gatttol-solved), I'm dealing with the Bluetooth stuff. I'm using the Bluez 5.4x C API.
At the moment, I'm able to scan and open a connection with a BLE device either using the command line or my C code.

To do this I'm working with the HCI API, so after:

```
id = hci_get_route(NULL);
dd = hci_open_dev(id);
hci_le_set_scan_enable();
hci_le_create_conn();
```

I achieve a connection handle = 71. At this point, I'd like to encrypt the link using the C equivalent for the hcitool enc functionality in C. However, I can't do this.

Once, the connection is established I check for the available connection using:

```
hcitool con
```

that returns:

```
< LE <bdaddr> handle 71 state 7 lm MASTER
```

so I suppose that my C code works, at least up to this point. 
If I try to encrypt the link invoking the `hci_encrypt_link()` function the system fails and returns:

***Get connection info failed: No such file or directory***

To test if the behavior is correct, I tried to execute the same operational flow from the command line executing:

```
sudo hcitool lescan
sudo hcitool lecc --random <bdaddr> - return: connection handle 71
sudo hcitool enc <bdaddr> - return: Not connected
```

Can anyone help me to identify the solution?